# Kotlin. Проверка введенного значения "на Int"

Tags: kotlin

Пытаюсь написать код, который выполнится при введении Int - значения. Не получается. Прошу помочь.

```
fun Number1(): Int {
    var isValidInput = false
    var UserChoice: Int = 0
    while(!isValidInput) {
        println("Введите целое число №1:")
        val UserInput = readLine()
        if (UserInput != null && UserInput is Int) { // ***тут подчеркивает Int***
            isValidInput = true
            UserChoice = UserInput
        }
        if (!isValidInput) println("Введено неверное значение, попробуйте снова.")
    }
    return UserChoice
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Раз подчёркивает, значит, что-то пишет. Наводи мышку и читай.

Comment: Подчеркнутый Int выводит эту ошибку: "Incompatible types: Int and String?". Могу только предположить, что нужно определить тип для **val UserInput = readLine()**

Comment: "UserInput is Int" - такая формулировка используется в Kotlin при работе с полями, тип которых может меняться (см. <Any>, <T> на сайте kotlin). В вашем же случае переменная UserInput всегда одного типа - String.

Comment: Спасибо, отработаю этот вопрос.  Безмерно Вам благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос можно решить несколькими путями:

1 - использовать конвертацию

```kotlin
val UserInput = readLine().toIntOrNull()

if (UserInput != null)
```

2 - использовать проверку

```kotlin
if (UserInput.all { it.isDigit() })
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Надеюсь, сработает.

Comment: Danil, все заработало. Большое Вам спасибо! (Учусь, каких то вещей еще не знаю)